# Community Registration on iPad opens SF1 in Mobile Browser

Tags: community, ipad, registration

I have created a branded home page / landing page using Community Builder. When a new community user register through the standard registration process in a browser, he is forwarded to the custom home page directly after submitting the registration, which is of course the expected behaviour.

However, when a new community user goes through the same registration process using the iPad, he is automatically forwarded to the mobile browser app displaying the Salesforce 1 home page instaed of the expected community home page.

Has anyone an idea how we can provide the same registration experience for our iPad users as we have with a standard browser ?

Thank you very much,
Ralf